# Usar resultado de un array en otra consulta php

Tags: php, html, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Hola apenas soy nuevo en PHP y en Mysql quiero hacer una consulta con el resultado de un de otra consulta arrar

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION[' u_usuario'])){
    $usuario1 = $_SESSION[' u_usuario'];
}
else{
    header("Location: index.php");
} 
include("conexion.php");
$refcuatri = " II2018 "; //Cambiar cuatrimestre para prevenir errores
//busqueda por del alumno por cuatrimester y matricula
$query3= mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT refgrupo, refcarrera FROM inscripcion WHERE refcuatri='$refcuatri' AND matricula ='$usuario1'");
$q3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3); 
$refgrupo=$q3['refgrupo']; // es igual a 4-A 
$refcarrera=$q3['refcarrera']; //es igual a SI
//busqueda del profesr por referencia del grupo y referencia de la carre que anteriormente se habia creado las variables
//A PARTIR DE AQUI NO ME LEE LAS VARIABLES PARA HACER OTRA CONSULTA
$query4= mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT refprofesor FROM asigna_materia WHERE refgrupo='$refgrupo' AND refcarrera='$refcarrera'");
$q4 = mysqli_fetch_array($query4);
$refprofesor=$q4['refprofesor']; //NO DA VALOR

echo $refgrupo; // ES IGUAL A 4-A
echo $refcarrera; // ES IGUAL A SI
echo $refprofesor; // NO DA VALOR
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ese es el resultado pero a partir del query4 no toma las variables la información que tiene dentro de ella para hacer otra búsqueda alguien me podría ayudar :c

los campos están correctos!

Answer (score 0):

Mete tu consulta `query3` a un `while` para que cicle el resultado, otra cosa, siempre que concatenes variables, corta la cadena, aveces no funciona directo, en la validación de la variable de `sesión u_usuario`, te serviría más un `empty()`

```
<?php
session_start();
if (!empty($_SESSION[' u_usuario'])){
    $usuario1 = $_SESSION[' u_usuario'];
}

else{
    header("Location: index.php");
} 

include("conexion.php");
$refcuatri = " II2018 "; //Cambiar cuatrimestre para prevenir errores
//busqueda por del alumno por cuatrimester y matricula
$query3= mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT refgrupo, refcarrera FROM inscripcion WHERE refcuatri='". $refcuatri. "' AND matricula ='".$usuario1."'");
while( $q3 = mysqli_fetch_array($query3) ){
  $refgrupo=$q3['refgrupo']; // es igual a 4-A 
  $refcarrera=$q3['refcarrera']; //es igual a SI
  //busqueda del profesr por referencia del grupo y referencia de la carre que anteriormente se habia creado las variables
  //A PARTIR DE AQUI NO ME LEE LAS VARIABLES PARA HACER OTRA CONSULTA
  $query4= mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT refprofesor FROM asigna_materia WHERE refgrupo='".$refgrupo."' AND refcarrera='".$refcarrera."'");
  $q4 = mysqli_fetch_array($query4);
  $refprofesor=$q4['refprofesor']; //NO DA VALOR

  echo $refgrupo; // ES IGUAL A 4-A
  echo $refcarrera; // ES IGUAL A SI
  echo $refprofesor; // NO DA VALOR
} 

?>
```

Comment: No me funciono con el método del Alberto Siurob :c alguien me puede ayudar mas por favor :c

Comment: Cual fue el error

Comment: Me sale igual pero cuando intento poner los valores de las variables del resultado query3  en el query4 si me muestra el resultado correctamente pero con variables no